# Can't access a non-root systemd service with systemctl

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I'm a systemd newbie, apologies in advance if what I ask is trivial.

I'm trying to use systemd for a service that periodically downloads data from binance. Everything works fine and it starts after booting, but I can't access it with systemctl. When I run `systemctl status binance-sync` I get

```
Unit binance-sync.service could not be found.
```

Nevertheless it does run. I believe the issue relates to the fact this is a non-root service. The binance-sync.service is located in `~/.config/systemd/user`, and it has a link in `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants`. When running `systemd-cgls` I can see under `user@1001.service` an entry `binance-sync.service` with the list of processes it has activated.

Any idea how can I access it via systmctl? Specifically I would like to be able to stop/restart it.

Here's the service file if it helps:

```
[Unit]
Description=Binance data sync service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/shay-work/IdeaProjects/Tarde/src/main/python/scripts
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/shay-work/IdeaProjects/Tarde/src/main/python/scripts/binance_sync.bash
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question should be on superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access user service add `--user`.

```
systemctl status --user binance-sync
```